# Types from lib.dom.d.ts not found when building

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following simple constructor function:

```
constructor() {
    const myTextAlign: CanvasTextAlign = 'center';
    const myHTMLDoc: HTMLDocument = null;
    console.log(myTextAlign);
}
```

VS Code reports no issues with the code, and if I click on `CanvasTextAlign` or `HTMLDocument` and press F12 it correctly takes me to the `lib.dom.d.ts`. However when I try to run `ng build` the Angular compiler throws the following error:

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'CanvasTextAlign'.`

It never reports an error about the `HTMLDocument` so it seems it can find *some* definitions in the `lib.dom.d.ts` but not all of them.

tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The tsconfig.app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Both json files are vanilla versions that were created when `ng new` was run

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like ? Specifically do you have any `libs` specified ?

Comment: That looks fine. And `tsconfig.app.json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell angular, *which* CanvasTextAlign you mean.

Use something like this, at the top of your controller ts file:

```
import {CanvasTextAlign} from 'mylibrary';
```

And make sure, that this libary is in your `node_modules` directory.

`HTMLDocument` on the other hand does not need such an import, it is part of angular itself.

Comment: This isn't quite right, but it did put me on the right path. Although VS Code's "Go to definition" was working, it was taking me to a lib.dom.d.ts that wasnt in my project. There are about 6 versions of this file in my project and none of them have this type declaration.